# What kind of metal are RF shields made of?

Tags: rf, wifi

With the shields typically found on WiFi modules, what kind of metal are they? Are they coated? Here's an example:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They could be made out of brass or other materials, but typically they're cold-rolled steel (CRS) with tin plating (for solderability and corrosion resistance).

You can easily check with a magnet.

Comment: `You can easily check with a magnet.` That would still leave you with a big amount of materials to choose from.

Comment: @Mast If it's magnetic (as is most likely) it's almost surely tin-plated CRS. So, this has a 90%+ chance of nailing it.

Answer (score 4):

Tin-plated steel is the most common shield material used on these devices.

The steel provides the strength and shielding while the tin plate reduces the tendency for rusting and allows easy soldering.

Answer (score -1):

You might be interested in MuMetal: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu-metal

Comment: Jeff, this is too thin for an answer on EE.SE.  Please elaborate.

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question, which is about what *existing* RF shields are made of. Mu-metal is used for *magnetic* shielding.